# How to identify the entry in an archive as a file or a folder in C#?

Tags: c#, archive, 7zip

I want to use the command line to unzip the archive in different conditions.

If there is only one file in the archive, then unzip to the folder with the same name of the archive, and if there is only a folder, then unzip directly to the path without adding a folder.

So I need to get the attribute of an entry in the archive. How to identify the entry of an archive as a file or a folder no matter the archive is .zip .rar, .7z

Until now, I use the 7z command line `7z l archive.zip` to get the list of the entry in the archive, and I don't know whether is there a better way to **Read** the archive for the identify result of the entry.

```
Date         Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
--------- --------------- ------------ ------------  -----------------------
2021-12-28 09:20:20 D....            0            0  MyNewFold
2021-12-28 09:20:06 ....A            0            0  MyNewFold\My New Document (2).txt
2021-12-28 09:19:53 ....A            0            0  MyNewFold\My New Document.txt
2021-12-28 09:36:02 ....A            0            0  My New Document.txt
2021-12-28 09:36:02                  0            0  3 files, 1 folders
```

> Through the result, I can slice the **Attr** String 'D' or 'A' with the entry
> name to identify it is a file or a folder temporarily.

1

I searched the keywords in Google, but there were many said that use ZipFile or ZipArchive through .NET API System.IO.Compression.

After getting the entry in the archive, identify if there is '\' at the end of the full path.

May this only suit for .zip, and I need it can check the entry is a file or folder in both .zip .rar .7z

2

Others using `System.IO.Directory.Exists(str)` to identify an entry path is a directory or file, may this not suit for the path of an entry in the archive.

There is a folder named MyNewFold in the **archive.zip** or archive.rar, and I test this, the result is 'None', instead of 'Folder'

```
var str = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\archive.zip\\MyNewFold";
if(System.IO.Directory.Exists(str)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Folder")
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("None")
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: @Progman:  This isn't a troubleshooting question, it is a "How To" question, and a tightly-focused one at that.  Treat it accordingly.

Comment: @lyscop: The title of your question is very clear; the body of your question is not.  Can you make it a little clearer?

Comment: using `System.IO.Directory.Exists` only checks for file system directories, not ones in other file systems like a compressed file. you'll have to open it using the appropriate code and decode it

Comment: This folder `MyNewFold` is within a zipped folder so `Exists` cannot look inside the zipped folder thus your code ouputs "None". Find code online for how to unzip and then use `Exists`. You can unzip to a temporary location, do your folder and file checking using `Exists` and then move it from the temporary location to a location as per your requirements in your question.

Comment: I don't think you can zip folders, only files. 7zip only groups the files by "folders"